# Proof of fundamental theorem of arithmetic: uniqueness assertion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a proof of the uniqueness assertion from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. I cannot fully understand the proof from reading my lecture notes. Here is my attempt to paraphrase and expand on what I wrote down. We're following Ireland and Rosen's book, so $(a,b)$ denotes the $\gcd$ of $a,b$ and $\text{ord}_p (n)$ is the highest power $a$ of $p$ such that $p^a$ divides $n$.

> By the existence assertion, we have
> $$
> n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}
> $$
> where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and $e_i > 0$. Let $p$ be an arbitrary prime. The goal is to show that the exponent $a \geq 0$ of $p$ in the factorization of $n$ depends only on $n$, and not on the factorization. If $p \neq p_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, then $p$ does not divide $p_i^{a_i}$ by Euclid's lemma, so $\text{ord}_p (p_i^{a_i}) = 0$. By virtue of the fact that $\text{ord}_n (ab) = \text{ord}_n (a) + \text{ord}_n (b)$ and induction, we have
> $$
> \text{ord}_p (n) = \text{ord}_p (p_1^{e_1}) + \ldots + \text{ord}_p (p_k^{e_k}). 
> $$
> So if $p \neq p_i$, then $\text{ord}_p (n) = 0 + \ldots + 0 = 0$, so $p$ does not divide $n$ and is not contained in any factorization of $n$. **Suppose now that $p = p_i$ for some $i$. Let $e$ be the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $n$. Then $e = e_i$ so $\text{ord}_n (p_i) = e$, $e = \text{ord}_p (n)$, and $n = \prod\limits_{p} p^{\text{ord}_p (n)}$.**

The last case is what I'm most confused against. If $p = p_i$ then $p$ is one of the primes in the factorization so it divides $n$. Let's call it $p_1$, reshuffling the indices if necessary. Then at least $p_1^{e_1}$ divide $n$. It seems obvious that then $\text{ord}_{p_1} (n) = e_1$, but I can't think of a way to show this formally. I'm not sure if I can use Euclid's lemma here: that $p$ divides $ab$ only if $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. As $p_1^{e_1}$ isn't necessarily a prime. I'm also a bit confused on the final step, though I believe what the proof is trying to say is that, if $p$ is one of the $p_i$, then $\text{ord}_p (n)$ is fixed and uniquely determined because it's equal to the exponent of $p_i$.

I'd appreciate any help with understanding this proof.

Comment: The proof shows that given *any* prime factorization of $\,n\,$ the power of $\,p\,$ that occurs in it is the highest power of $\,p\,$ dividing $\,n,\,$ i.e. ${\nu}_p(n),\,$ so the factorization is $\, n = \prod\, {p_i}^{\large {\nu}_{p_i}(n)},\,$ hence *uniqueness*.

Comment: @BillDubuque This is helpful, though I'm a little confused on how we can conclude that the power of $p$ is the highest such power. It seems that, in theory, different factorizations could give different powers. The only idea that comes to mind is either Euclid's lemma or a sort of "cancellation" law for excess powers.

Comment: The proof shows $\,\nu_{p_i}(n) = \nu_{p_i}(p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}) = \nu_{p_i}(p^{e_i}) = e_i,\,$ i.e. the power $\,e\,$ of $\,p\,$ in any prime factorization of $\,n\,$ equals the highest power of $\,p\,$ dividing $\,n\,$ (which is *unique*, i.e. $\,\nu_p(n)\,$ is (well-)defined as: $ $  max $\,j\,$ with $\,p^j\mid n;\,$ it is *not* defined by any prime factorization).

Comment: It is not *obvious* that $\,\nu_{p_i}(n) = e_i.\,$ Rather it depends crucially on $\,\nu_p(xy) = \nu_p(x) + \nu_p(y),\,$ which is equivalent to Euclid's Lemma, which is equivalent to *uniqueness* of prime factorizations.